# How to make sure webpack bundles eval() functions in node environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, webpack, eval

I'm writing some unsafe eval() based code which is being used for assignment. Like this:

```
var myName;
eval("myName = 10")
```

But what webpack is doing is mangling the myName identifier to some random letter.

This is breaking the eval function as well.

Is there a way to not mangle certain variables in webpack, or is it capable of parsing eval statements with some special  plugin?

Comment: You should probably be asking how to remove your `eval` calls...

Comment: @VLAZ nope, the eval function is required in my context. I would have removed it if I could, so what can be the possible solution?

Comment: Use an object instead `obj = {}; obj["myName"] = 10`.

Comment: @VLAZ as I said, I have tried all possible solutions but the eval method is the only way I can solve this, so yeah, if you have solution, please write it

Comment: Perhaps a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), since you didnt mentation what the problem is? There is nearly no real use case for eval.

Comment: @Marc yes, since the actual code is around 600 lines long, I don't want to mention it. But I can say for sure that I'm using eval to assing a value to a variable that I actually don't know. But don't worry, I know what kind of value is expected, so I purify it using regex before using eval to avoid loopholes.

Comment: Why would you need to do that instead of using an object/Map?